# Websockets over WebAssembly generated by golang?

Tags: go, websocket, webassembly, gorilla

Is it possible to write a Websocket client in wasm over go? I have tried using `gorilla/websocket`, but no success:

```
func main() {
    ws := func(this js.Value, inputs []js.Value) interface{} {
        go func() {
            wsDial, r, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial("ws://localhost:3000/ws", nil)
            fmt.Println(wsDial, r, err)
        }()
        return nil
    }

    js.Global().Set("ws", js.FuncOf(ws))

    select {}
}
```

I get the following error when calling `ws()`:

```
dial tcp: Protocol not available
```

Comment: You should take a look at the example client: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/echo/client.go

Comment: @newplayer65 Thank you, but I know how to implement the client, as you can see I am doing the same thing as at the line 32 in the example. Actually this is not about the library, but more about go and wasm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have solved it by retrieving the `WebSocket` object from the global `JavaScript` object, which in my case is `window` because I am running this in a browser. I have used only the "syscall/js" library. It looks like this:

```
ws := js.Global().Get("WebSocket").New("ws://localhost:8080/ws")

ws.Call("addEventListener", "open", js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
    fmt.Println("open")

    ws.Call("send", js.TypedArrayOf([]byte{123}))
    return nil
}))
```

Comment: That seems to be right because it should be impossible to create WebSocket object inside WASM. For the you must call outside and that is what you are doing.

Comment: quick note, js.TypedArrayOf no longer exists. you can just send a string in ws.Call("send", "message")

Answer (score 6):

`gorilla/websocket` does not support web assembly.  I've ended up using [nhooyr/websocket](https://github.com/nhooyr/websocket) which supports wasm.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of the client working with nhooyr/websocket in wasm?

Comment: I would also like to see  that :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [gopherJS websocket library](https://github.com/gopherjs/websocket). This one was created to run in the browser (originally js).

I recently saw a youtube video with it being in use in WASM but I couldn't find it any more.

Comment: I took a look over it, pretty interesting. Do you have an idea about what's the difference between gopherjs/js and syscall/js, which one is best suited for wasm, from the doc it seems like syscall/js is

Comment: gopherjs and wasm support for go are both created by `Richard Musiol`. `syscall/js` is adjusted for wasm so I'd use that one.

Comment: @tehspinx yes, and also after some research I learned that gopher/js is kind of dying, so yeah, syscall/js would be the rational choice

Comment: yeah... why compile to js if you can compile to wasm :D